# Convert Twos complement form of a number to signed decimal

Tags: java

I have this String representation of a number -2 which I got using this function

```
Integer.toBinaryString(signed-int);
```

so I put -2 and got 11111111111111111111111111111110

I performed few operations and now I want to convert the string 11111111111111111111111111111110 into -2 again. How do I do it?

In general how do I convert twos complement representation of a number to its signed decimal form?

Comment: Look into Integer.parseInt(String, int)

Comment: For what it's worth, `Integer` is not a "signed decimal." You'd need to use `BigDecimal` or something similar to get a true decimal representation. What you're wanting to do is convert from a binary string representation back to a binary integer representation.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
int x = (int)Long.parseLong(s, 2);
```

`Integer.parseInt` cannot parse `"11111111111111111111111111111110"` because it takes it as a positive binary number